# Cannot remove package

Tags: debian, apt, services, dpkg

On a Debian headless server I made an error: NTP and OPENNTP are conflicting. The result is that I cannot update date/time.

Long time ago I was trying to set a NTP client and it looks like I crashed something trying to install both of them.

Both services are not active and `service --status-all` doesn't list them. Just to be sure there are no pending services I reboot the unit.

I am trying to remove both packages and reinstall from scratch only NTP, but for EVERY cleanup of OPENNTPD using `apt` (and the related `dpkg`) I get the same error:

```
Removing openntpd (20080406p-10) ...
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: unable to link /etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service to /dev/null: File exists
dpkg: error processing package openntpd (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openntpd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

NTP has (after some suffering) been removed and purged.

OPENNTPD is instead half installed:

```
# dpkg-query -l openntpd
rH  openntpd      20080406p-10        amd64        OpenBSD NTP daemon
```

I already tried to remove, upgrade, purge, force reinstall OPENNTPD, at no avail:

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install  (same error)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get remove openntpd
dpkg -r openntpd
dpkg --purge openntpd
dpkg --remove --force-all openntpd
```

return always the same error.

It `cannot link to /dev/null` and I find no info about this error online.

Comment: deb-systemd-helper is executing `ln -s /etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service /dev/null`. Quite possibly you should just remove this file on your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you need to remove `/etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service` manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/openntpd.service
```

Then you should be able to purge `openntpd`.

Comment: Thank you, @Stephen Kitt and Stefan M. I removed the link and it works. Don't know why I didn't do it before :-(